# Excel VBA - if loop with dynamic filter range

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following table:

```
Filter   Notional  Type   Total
A          5000    A      _____
B          1000    A
           2500    B
           3600    C
           7500    C
           8000    B
           4500    C
           700     C
```

And the following code in order to calculate the filtered sum of notional values:

```
    Sub filtersum()

    Dim filterA, filterB as Variant
        filterA = Cells (2, 1)
        filterB = Cells (3, 1)

    Dim i, n as Integer
        k = Cells.Find("Type").Offset(1, 0).Row
        n = Cells.Find("Type").End(xlDown).Row

    Dim sum as Double
        sum = 0

    For i = k To n
    If Cells(i, 3) = filterA Or Cells(i, 3) = filterB Then
        j = Cells(i, 3)
           sum = j + sum 
        End If
    Next i 

    Cells.(2, 4).Value = sum    'Result under "Total"

    End Sub
```

So what I am doing right now is calculating the sum of all notional values, that are Type "A" or "B". But for the final application this is not sufficient because now I am defining every single filter criteria in the code (fiterA, filterB). The user should be able to add filter criteria in the table like:

```
Filter   Notional  Type   Total
A          5000    A      _____
B          1000    A
C          2500    B
           3600    C
           7500    C
           8000    B
           4500    C
           700     C
```

Right now I would have to prepare the code and add another criteria for the if condition, which is not desirable in the final application.

I hope you have any ideas to solve my problem, Thanks!

Comment: I would use SUMIFS function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of "hard coding" each filter cell in the IF statement, I loop through the filter column.

For each `g` (filter value in range "Filter"), it will check for every row if the criteria is found in column "Type" (Column `C`). If match is found it will sum. When one filter criteria is done (`g`) it will go to next row in "Filter" column.

```
Sub filtersum()

Dim filterA As Variant, filterB As Variant
    filterA = Cells(2, 1)
    filterB = Cells(3, 1)

Dim k As Long, n As Long, h As Long
    k = Cells.Find("Type").Offset(1, 0).Row
    n = Cells.Find("Type").End(xlDown).Row
    h = Cells.Find("Filter").End(xlDown).Row 'last row for column A, searching for "Filter"

Dim sum As Double
    sum = 0 'Sum variable


Dim g As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim filterCriteria As Variant 'Define your criteria it should look up


For g = k To h 'Look up for Filter column, from the same start cell as "Type" column to the same end cell as "Type". Then loop through all criterias.
    filterCriteria = Cells(g, 1).Value 'Get current criteria value
    For i = k To n 'Loop through column Type
        If Cells(i, 3) = filterCriteria Then 'If Type = filter criteria, then sum.
            j = Cells(i, 2) 'I think you have an typo in your example here, since sum should be done on column B, not column C.
            sum = j + sum 'Sum the values.
        End If
    Next i 'take next value in column C, "Type" column
Next g 'take next value in column A, "Filter" column
Cells(2, 4).Value = sum    'Result under "Total"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly the kind of solution I was looking for!

Comment: I'm happy to help. You did most of the work. I just looped it one more time ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use sumifs. I would then extend the formula down as needed. That's the formula for cell D2
[image]

Comment: Thank you, for the quick response, but this solution is not quite helpfull for me. I need a dynamic criteria range, so if the user adds a filter criteria, i dont want to prepare my vba code.

Comment: Why can't you add the sum of column D in Cell "E2" ? then you got your total and you can specify additional filters in column A. (make sure that the formula in column D is copied to as many rows as necessary

Comment: This is just a example table, in my application I don't have the possibility for this step inbetween

Answer (score 0):

you can use `AutoFilter()` method with `xlFilterValues` as its `Operator` parameter value and `WorksheetFunction.Subtotal()` function to sum up filtered cells, as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub filtersum()

    Dim filters As Variant
    filters = Application.Transpose(Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value)

    With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=filters, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Range("D2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, .Columns(1))
    End With
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```